# Python intersection of 2 dataframes with list-type columns

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have two dataframes with only a list-type column for each. I wanted to get an output dataframe that has only those list-values common in both given dataframes (order of list-elements do not matter).

```
**df1**
column name: pm
[a,b,c]
[g,h,k]
[i,l]
[k]

**df2**
column_name:fm
[c,b,a]
[k,l,m]
[g,k,h]
[l]

**df3**
pm        fm
[a,b,c]   [c,b,a]
[g,h,k]   [g,k,h]
```

df3 should preserve the order of elements in pm and fm, but to match the intersection rule, set(pm) needs to match set(fm).

Please let me know if you can help in this

Answer (score 0):

Add another column named "key" in both dataframes and then merge two dataframes using inner join on "key" column.

"Key" column is the sorted list of pm and fm in df1 and df2 respectively

```
df1['key'] = df1.pm.sort_values().apply(lambda x: sorted(x))
df2['key'] = df1.fm.sort_values().apply(lambda x: sorted(x))
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on=['key'])
```